# Differences between H20 dataframes and Spark RDD

Tags: h2o

I am abit investigating the h2o framework to work with its extra machine learning tool. I am just curious what is the differences between an H20 dataframes and Spark RDDs. Is the h2o dataframes can be cached or persisted like Spark RDDs?

Answer (score 4):

H2O frames are not lazy, contrary to Spark's data structures. There is therefore no need for explicit caching/persisting as we load the whole frame into memory anyway. This can be problematic if your dataset is bigger than cluster's memory but we do it in such a way for performance reasons. In spark you'd cache RDDs for machine learning anyway. There are 2 requirements for an H2O frame:

- the total cluster memory has to be big enough to hold the whole frame
- a single row of the frame has to fully fit on every machine (we do not distribute frames column-wise, only row-wise meaning we take X rows, a chunk, and put them all on a single node)

H2O frames just like RDDs are fully distributed and only parts of the frame are located on each node. Most of our algos take advantage of data locality (i.e. each node only uses rows stored on it for computations) but you can also shuffle data around so every node uses the whole frame.

When converting an RDD into an H2O frame we materialize the whole data in memory. When doing the opposite there's no memory overhead as we're just iterating over an H2O Frame.

H2O frames are less generic than RDDs but thanks to that we can highly compress the data in memory.